# Batch-generate Emacs byte-compiled files in a custom directory

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm generating byte-compiled files (*.elc) using the `batch-byte-compile` function. This function writes out the *.elc files in the same directory as the *.el files.

How can I have Emacs generate the byte-compiled files in a different directory?

An ideal solution would be operational system agnostic.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The convention that the .elc files reside in the same directory.  For example: how do you know your central .elc files refer to the versions you think?  What if you have the same .el file in your personal site-lisp and shipped with emacs?

Comment: I need to test that the byte-compiled files are errors and warnings free in a test-suite.

Comment: You'll presumably still want `.elc` files alongside the original `.el` files though, yes? So the script invoking `batch-byte-compile` could just copy the files when it's done? Or not: Depending on `load-prefer-newer` (in recent versions), Emacs will prefer compiled files to uncompiled files, so you could load them from their original location. You could also go a step further by modifying `load-suffixes` in your test code so that Emacs *only* looks for the byte-compiled files? (you would, of course, need to ensure that all required libraries were compiled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs uses `byte-compile-dest-file` to generate a compiled file name from a source file name.  That function delegates to customizable variable `byte-compile-dest-file-function` if non-nil.

So you can simply define it.  Something like this:

```
(defun my-byte-compile-dest-file (source-file)
  (concat (file-name-directory source-file)
          "prefix-"
          (file-name-base source-file)
          "-compiled"))
(setq byte-compile-dest-file-function 'my-byte-compile-dest-file)
```

Comment: from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957049/setting-byte-compile-dest-file-function/13957827#13957827), the `byte-compile-dest-file-function` variable was used by Emacs 23.2. I'm using Emacs 24.5 and it seems this variable is not used any more, so I cannot use your solution.

Comment: I'm not on the same computer anymore, but I'm confident it was GNU Emacs 24.5 as well (Arch Linux's current), so you should be fine. Have you tried?

Comment: `byte-compile-dest-file-function` is most certainly defined (by `bytecomp`) in 24.5.1