# How to output elisp bytecode to a custom directory?

Tags: emacs, makefile

I need to output elisp bytecode generated by `batch-compile` to a custom directory. The customisation value `byte-compile-dest-file-function` seems to be relevant for this:

```
(defcustom byte-compile-dest-file-function nil
  "Function for the function `byte-compile-dest-file' to call.
It should take one argument, the name of an Emacs Lisp source
file name, and return the name of the compiled file."
  :group 'bytecomp
  :type '(choice (const nil) function)
  :version "23.2")
```

I went as far as `/opt/local/bin/emacs -batch --eval '(defun my-dest-file-function (filename) (let ((pwd (expand-file-name ".")) (basename (replace-regexp-in-string ".*/" "" filename))) (concat (file-name-as-directory pwd) basename "c"))) (setq byte-compile-dest-file-function (quote my-dest-file-function)) (batch-byte-compile)' /Users/michael/Workshop/project/example/elisp/example1.el`

The *elisp* code is easier to read in its unwrapped form:

```
(defun my-dest-file-function (filename)
 (let ((pwd (expand-file-name "."))
       (basename (replace-regexp-in-string ".*/" "" filename)))
 (concat (file-name-as-directory pwd) basename "c")))
(setq byte-compile-dest-file-function (quote my-dest-file-function))
(batch-byte-compile)
```

The function `my-dest-file-function` computes the correct filenames but it does not seem to be used at all, nor the `(batch-byte-compile)` function to be used at all.

How can I correct the *elisp* code above to produce the desired effect? I want to avoid any single quote in the *elisp* code to work easily with the shell and Makefiles.

*My emacs version is 24.5.1.*

Comment: See [Setting byte compile dest file function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957049/setting-byte-compile-dest-file-function)

Comment: `batch-byte-compile` is intended to be invoked with `-f`.  I'm guessing you should use a different compilation function for this.

Comment: @tripleee This usage is legit, see Brian's answer for the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the whole thing in a `progn`:

```
(progn
  (defun my-dest-file-function (filename)
    (let ((pwd (expand-file-name "."))
          (basename (replace-regexp-in-string ".*/" "" filename)))
      (concat (file-name-as-directory pwd) basename "c")))
  (setq byte-compile-dest-file-function (quote my-dest-file-function))
  (batch-byte-compile))
```

Before, you were only executing the first statement, `defun`, which does nothing on its own.

Comment: Argh, I was so close! ;)  This is exactly what I needed to know, thank you very much!